# Timepicker appears behind the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datetimepicker

I am using JQuery's Timepicker plug in. Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="time">Time of Event</label>
     <input  id="time" class="timepicker" >
     </input>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.timepicker').timepicker({});
});
</script>
```

However, I get something like this:[image]

As you can see, the timepicker appears behind the modal form and I am unable to access it. I think this has something to do with the z-index so I am playing around with that. However, I am unsuccessful at this time.

This is what I tried: `<input id="time" class="timepicker" style="z-index:1151 !important" >`

Any ideas?

EDIT: Okay, so for some reason when I try to change the `z-index` of the `timepicker` it doesn't get changed. It's like its getting overridden by something. However, if I manually change it in the `Google Chrome Inspect` window it works.

Comment: set z-index for `.ui-timepicker-container`, like this : `.ui-timepicker-container{
       z-index:1151 !important;
}`

Comment: I tried that and it worked! Wow thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to apply `z-index` for `timepicker` container.

```
.ui-timepicker-container{ 
     z-index:1151 !important; 
}
```